# Integer array pointer implementation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,5,6};
int *apnt= a;
while (*apnt)
{
 printf("The no is %d\n",*apnt);
 apnt++;
}
```

Unlike strings, I am aware that there is no null element at the end of the array. However, my code always gives the following output, no matter how many times i flush the memory, or restart xcode. What is happening here? Can some one give me an insight?

The output is:

```
The no is 1
The no is 2
The no is 3
The no is 5
The no is 6
The no is 32767
The no is 144723190
The no is 1694538263
The no is 1606416704
The no is 32767
The no is -1982110263
The no is 32767
```

Comment: you have undefined behavior. so?

Comment: If you are aware there is no null added to the end, why do you expect `while (*apnt)` to do anything useful for you?

Comment: You've described what you observe, but not how this is different from what you expect. Since there's nothing 'wrong' with the output we need to know what you expected in order to correct whatever misapprehension you have.

Comment: I hope you do realise that by using while (*apnt) you're pointing to the first element of the array which is 1; that has the effect of making the while loop an infinite loop. Try removing the deference operator.

Comment: @bames53: he said that "my code always gives the following output, no matter how many times i flush the memory, or restart xcode". In other words, he would expect the "wrong" output (after 1 2 3 5 6) to change every time, as the content of those memory addresses should be random. Instead, it's always the same. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading past the end of an array is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What you see, even if you see anything, is not predictable by C++ language rules.

You get this output by chance, it may differ on every machine, even with every run. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63c128df977d2c9f) it did something else, but it really could do literally *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answerers are mistaking the intention of your question - I assume you're not trying to find undefined behavior in C++, just looking to iterate over your array. The problem in your code, is that you keep incrementing the pointer `apnt` past the end of the array. This is undefined behavior, and anything could happen.

However, usually what happens in this case, is you will continue to read the memory that is *after* the `a` array (the other local variables in your function). This explains why the 'garbled' output is predictable. You should instead only iterate over the number of elements in the array (eg. With a for loop), OR you could add a '0' to the end of your array, so the while loop will terminate.

Comment: Yes, I know what is wrong. My intent was not to loop till the end of array (which i do know how to do), but was to understand why I was getting a certain behaviour. Thanks for the help!  Now i see that it is an undefined behaviour!